# Django: If I pass an instance to a form, then call is_valid(), are the instances fields validated?

Tags: django, django-forms

May be a simple question, but if I have a ModelForm:

```
class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['username']
```

When I use the form, I want to inject a username I've got from elsewhere, but still want it to go through the validation process. If I use:

```
instance = ExampleModel(username='Foobar')
form = ExampleModelForm(request.POST, instance=instance)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Does the username 'Foobar' go through the same validation as the rest of the fields in the form?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the form doesn't even contain the username field if it has been excluded.

If you want to perform validation on the field through the form, you should modify the POST dictionary.

```
post = request.POST.copy()
post['username'] = 'Foobar'

form = ExampleForm(post)
```

Comment: Interesting - so what does binding the model instance to the form actually do then? On a related note, if you do what you suggest above still doesn't validate the fields, as they were excluded in the Meta for the form.

Comment: @jvc, the form would edit that specific instance instead of constructing one (which means it has your username, but will not undergo form validation because the field has been excluded). Yes, you would of course have to stop excluding `username` from the ModelForm.

Comment: Ah excellent. Cheers for the answer!. Is there any way to inject excluded variables, or is that just a wish too far?

Comment: @jvc26, I'm sorry can you clarify? Generally speaking you can cover anything required by either: modifying the `POST` dictionary (if you want validation) or setting instance attributes directly (if the data does not need validation) via `model_instance = form.save(commit=False)` which returns an unsaved instance of your model that you can do whatever you'd like with.